# Which of the Arcanist's features lets it swap out its prepared spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature

I've heard that the [Arcanist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist#TOC-Arcane-Reservoir-Su-), Pathfinder's Wizard/Sorcerer Hybrid, has the batspit insane capacity to swap out its prepared spells during the day, effectively making it a Wizard minus their biggest drawback: lack of spontaneity.

However, now that I look over its class features and exploits, I can't identify which feature it is that lets them do this. Which one is it? (Have I heard wrong? Am I thinking of the wrong class?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you're thinking of the [Quick Study](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/arcane-exploits/quick-study-su) exploit:

> The arcanist can prepare a spell in place of an existing spell by expending 1 point from her arcane reservoir.

Comment: This looks like the one.